# How to customize virtuemart coupon code process for multiple coupons [comma seperated] together when submit the coupon code?

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am a new devloper in the virtuemart extension in joomla. We have a website for shopping cart and client wants that when a user purchase any product from the site then he could enter multiple coupons at a time and get total discount from the total coupons used. So where i could start to do to working this thing. I am using joomla version 1.5.22 and virtuemart version 1.1.3.

Comment: The first thing you should do is get the site updated to Joomla 1.5.26 and Virtuemart 1.1.9. Then you should tell your client the bad news that the 1.5 series of Joomla is reaching end of life in September. They really need to get on Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2.0 before you start writing a bunch of code that will be obsolete in a few months.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [awocoupon](http://awodev.com/).  It allows multiple coupons, as well as a ton of other features that are missing from a robust couponing system.